# KeyListener receives the "key-hit" before my JTextField does..?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I got a `JTextField`, and to that field I have added a `Keylistener`. Inside the `keyPressed` method, I ask the method to print (`System.out.println`) whats inside the `JTextField`.. If I hit a letter, it seems as the `Keylistener` receives this key-hit before the `JTextField` is updated.. I have to hit two letters to see the first one..

All I need to do is to make every letter upper-case as they are inputted.. This I am trying to do by listening to every key (I also listen to the ENTER key for other reasons) and then do a `textfield.setText(textfield.getText().toUpperCase());`

Comment: Why can't you add a listener to the JTextField?

Comment: ".. and to that field I have added a KeyListener"

Comment: Duh. :) I thought you were using a global KeyListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its not so popular to answer your own question.. but I guess I found the solution.. Instead of doing all the upper-casing in the keyPressed method, I do it in the keyReleased :)

Answer (score 4):

Use a [DocumentFilter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) to alter the text as it comes in.

Not the prettiest source and it's not 100% correct, just showing how it works. [See the original here](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/225.html)

```
((AbstractDocument)textField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new UppercaseDocumentFilter());

  class UppercaseDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                                 String text, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {

            fb.insertString(offset, text.toUpperCase(), attr);
        }

        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
                            String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                throws BadLocationException {

            fb.replace(offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attrs);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the underlying document:

```
textfield.getDocument().addDocumentListener(yourListener);
```